# Where can I find list of the window API?

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading this [article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-introduction) about "Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs", in the middle of article when I read this code,

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
```

I'm curious about how many `window.*` is available on API? Where can I find another?

I can't find it with simple search on google.

Comment: Some here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: Heh, you can type `window.` in Chrome devtools and scroll through the list.

Comment: @Phil I can't find `window.FileReader` or other.  @qxz, I don't understand what i must to do

Comment: That's why I said "some" and not "all". You were asking for resources (which if off-topic for StackOverflow) and now you have somewhere to start. There's also plenty more here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Comment: Thanks a lot. it clear what i want, last question, Is it work with `window.*` word, so i can check browser support?

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for browser Javascript is the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) website:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Next time you need to google something, add `mdn` to your search and enjoy high-quality documentation.

Comment: thanks, but i can't find `window.File`, `window.FileReader`, `window.FileList` , Is it within another?

Comment: @AepSaepudin - which browser?

Comment: @Jaromanda, Chrome. It  answered, I can find it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API. But i'm curios Is it work with `window.*` word? so i can check browser support.

Comment: what is `window.* word` ?

Comment: like `window.File`, `window.FileReader` or other. Is it work too for example `window.AudioBuffer`,  `window.Gamepad` or else?

Comment: Just google those things man. If I search for `window.File mdn` the **first result** is the documentation